# django test server error: connection refused. How to deploy apps locally to test?

Tags: python, django, deployment, django-views

This is the first time I've developed a web app using Django and one of my first major attempts at programming.

I'm trying to deploy my project to the django test server- http://127.0.0.1:8000/ -but I get an error that says the connection is refused. I've looked through Django's documentation and and other websites about django deployment but I'm at a loss on how to troubleshoot this error.

If someone can recommend a way for me to deploy django locally so I can test my web app using django test server or recommend another deployment service that is easy for new programmers to use that would be very appreciated.

*edit: After doing what Ojas Kale had suggested I still am at a loss on what the possible issue or issues that are causing this error.*

Davis Joseph.

Comment: what do you have in your allowed_host list ? You can find this var in settings.py.

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] Should work

Comment: I tried ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] but I still get the same error. Is there another common error that causes this issue? Thanks for reaching out to me so quickly, @OjasKale

Comment: may be a port issue. ? Try python manage.py runserver 8888, and then try accessing it over localhost:8888/

Comment: The connection is still refused on localhost:8888/ but when I run python manage.py runserver 8888 it says "Performing system checks..." and then it ran my views.py in cmd. Is this supposed to happen? Got any more ideas about possible errors in my project? I can post code if need be @OjasKale.

Comment: yeah for Performing system checks... happens always.

Comment: Sure if you could paste the complete error that would be helpful

Comment: Is the complete error found on the test server page?  If so this is the error -"This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" If not, there are no errors popping up in my cmd.

Comment: this looks like a firewall issue, I never came across this. do ipconfig to get your ip and try python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.105:8000 . I am out of ideas already :D